# Delete Rows containing data: buffer issues

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete all rows containing "$" in Column C on approximately 10000 rows. I've tried this but it takes forever to complete. Someone has a quicker or more efficient way of doing this?

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "C").Value) = "$" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: You could disable and then enable screen updating while macro execution using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before your critical code, and at the end `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. This improves greatly the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using `.Find()`

```
Dim rng As Range
'Application.ScreenUpdateing = False  'don't enable this until you're sure the 
   'works correctly
Set rng = Range.Columns("C").Find(what:="$", LookIn:=xlValues)
While Not rng Is Nothing
  rng.EntireRow.Delete
  Set rng = Range.Columns("C").Find(what:="$", LookIn:=xlValues)
Wend
Set rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdateing = False
```

You'll probably want to add a couple of extra parameters to the `.Find()` call to specify exactly what you're looking for - it uses the parameters exactly as they're set in the `Find` dialog box unless you override them in code, and setting them in code is reflected the next time you open the `Find` dialog box, so you have to be very careful.

Comment: A) That's the recommendation I've always seen. B) It's usually faster to use built in functions than to try to write them yourself. C) Have you tried timing it to see which is faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate some useless features while you are operating, I added a Timer so that you can compare.

1st option, same action as you delete and no array :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim TimingT As Long
TimingT = Time

last = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "C").Value) = "$" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Total duration of operation : " & Format(Time - TimingT, "hh:mm:ss"), vbInformation, "Procedure finished"
```

2nd option, with an array :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim LastR As Long
Dim TimingT As Long
TimingT = Time
Dim ToDel()

LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
ReDim ToDel(LastR)

For i = 1 To UBound(ToDel)
    ToDel(i) = InStr(1, Cells(i, "C"), "$")
Next i

For i = UBound(ToDel) To 1 Step -1
    If ToDel(i) <> 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Total duration of operation : " & Format(Time - TimingT, "hh:mm:ss"), vbInformation, "Procedure finished"
```

3rd option, clearcontents and then sort (didn't do it but could be interesting...)